# Checkbox Label Image:hover?

Tags: html, css

I need a glowing background to the images that are displayed when you :hover the image. But I'm not sure whether you can or my selector is incorrect..?

```
                else {
                    $label = '<label>';
                    $label2 = '</label>';
                    $check = '<input class="check" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="'.$value.'">';
                    $value1 = $value;
                }

                echo $label.$check.$cards[$value1].$label2;
            }
```

So that is how my label displays the image of the card, which it does perfectly and displays a checkbox underneath the card. As well as the card being clickable.

```
.check {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 215px;
}

    .check img:hover {  
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,200,0,0.8);
    }
```

But I cannot seem to get a selector to target the image, to produce this outer glow effect, or more preferably overlay a green image over the image with a transparancy of about `30%`, how is it one is able to select the image of the label?

`<label><input class="check" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="'.$value.'"></label>`

Comment: Post your generated HTML instead of PHP code.

Comment: Done `<label><input class="check" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="'.$value.'"></label>`

Comment: Where exactly is the `<img>` within your HTML?

Comment: And where would be the image element?

Comment: The image element is stored in `$value` `"14" => "<img src=\"cards/2_of_clubs.png\"/>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

**HTML:**

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="check">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/115x200" alt="">
</label>
```

**CSS:**

```
label { position: relative; }

.check {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 215px;
}

.check:hover + img {  
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,200,0,0.8);
}
```

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/edAb/1/edit)**

If so, it would be better to use this selector instead:

```
label:hover img {  
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,200,0,0.8);
}
```

**[JSBin Demo #2](http://jsbin.com/edAb/2/edit)**

Comment: This works perfectly, I think I was missing the position relative also for the label, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN TRY THIS IT WILL WORK FINE.

```
.check {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 215px;
}

.check:hover ~ img {  
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,200,0,0.8);
}
```

if html is

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="check">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/115x200" alt="">
</label>
```

and if image is in input box you can try.

```
.check {
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: 50px;
      margin-top: 215px;
    }

    .check:hover img {  
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,200,0,0.8);
    }
```